# Kubernetes - ISTIO certificate issuer with letsencrypt reroute to https

Tags: kubernetes, istio, lets-encrypt

i am trying to configure issuer

```
 apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: zelafy-homeserver-letsencrypt
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: xxxxxx@hotmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: zelafy-homeserver-letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - selector:
        dnsNames:
        - "zelafy.xxxx.com"
      http01:
        ingress:
         class: istio
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: zelafy-homeserver-cert #change
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  secretName: zelafy-homeserver-tls-cert #change
  issuerRef:
    name: zelafy-homeserver-letsencrypt
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: "zelafy.xxx.com"
  dnsNames:
    - "zelafy.xxxx.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: zelafy
  namespace: homeserver
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "zelafy.xxxx.com"
    tls:
      ***httpsRedirect: true*** 
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: zelafy-homeserver-tls-cert  # This should match the Certificate secretName
    hosts:
    - "zelafy.xxxx.com" # This should match a DNS name in the Certificate
```

not working as when it try to authenticate the certificate it is redirected to https
but when i remove "httpsRedirect: true"
it work fine
i am using helm chart for deployment , any work around to prevent the letsencrypt trfic from rerouting to https ?

####### new Update 12/2/2021

i removed "httpsRedirect: true"
I created a 2 Gate ways , 1 for Http and one for https

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kaka  # name of the vservice
  namespace: kaka
spec:
  gateways:
  - kaka-https
  hosts: # incoming host
  - "kaka.mydoamain.com" # domaiin name
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: kaka
          subset: prod
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: kaka-https
  namespace: kaka
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: kaka-kaka-tls-cert 
    hosts:
    - "kaka.mydomain.com"
```

created a virtual service for Http point to a new ngix deployment for https redirect , for acme traffic it is not directed

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kaka-redirect  # name of the vservice
  namespace: kaka
spec:
  gateways:
  - kaka-http
  hosts: # incoming host
    - "kaka.mydomain.com" # domaiin name
  http:
    - name: "acme"
      match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /.well-known/acme-challenge
      route:
      - destination:
          host: kaka
    - name: "redir"
      route:
      - destination:
          host: redirect
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name _;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redirect
  labels:
    app: redirect
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
  selector:
    app: redirect
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redirect
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redirect
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redirect
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redirect
        image: nginx:stable
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: config
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config
```

now it redirect all to https except amce traffic

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Comment: Did you manage to find an easier solution?

Comment: @katomaso , i didnt find a solution , but as a workaround i created a POD to redirect the Http to Https , as stated in the update